# PostgreSQL with docker compose and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, docker-compose

Hey im trying to create a postgresql db container, im running it using the command:

```
docker-compose up
```

on the following compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: default_db
    ports:
      - 54320:5432
```

However when I try to connect to it using the follwoing python code:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgres://admin:admin@localhost:54320/default_db')
engine.connect()
```

I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: How is your postgres authentication configured? It appears that the client library is able to access Postgres, but not to authenticate. Try starting the containers, then doing`docker exec -it <postgres-container-id>  /bin/sh`, and try to connect to Postgres from within the container.

Comment: Try POSTGRES_USER instead of POSTGRES_USERNAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using POSTGRES_USER instead of POSTGRES_USERNAME solved this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should use POSTGRES_USER instead of POSTGRES_USERNAME.

Here is my postgres docker-compose configuration for your reference.

```
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        image: 'mdillon/postgis:latest'
        environment:
            - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWOR=postgres
        ports:
            - '15432:5432'
```